# How to sort by "sum of cost" in Grand total using app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, pivot-table, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to use app script to generate pivot table and sort by sum of one column in Grand Total. I have three column in the grand total.

```
function createCampaignPivotTable() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var sheetId = sheet.getSheetId();
  // The name of the sheet containing the data you want to put in a table.
  var pivotTableParams = {};

  // var customerId = getSourceTable();
  // The source indicates the range of data you want to put in the table.
  // optional arguments: startRowIndex, startColumnIndex, endRowIndex, endColumnIndex
  pivotTableParams.source = { 
    sheetId: sheetId
  };

  // Group rows, the 'sourceColumnOffset' corresponds to the column number in the source range
  // eg: 0 to group by the first column

  pivotTableParams.columns = [
    {
    sourceColumnOffset: 4,
    sortOrder: "ASCENDING",
      "showTotals": true,
      "valueBucket": {
                          "buckets": [
                            {
                              "stringValue": "Ad Destination"
                            }
                          ]
                        }
    }
  ];

  pivotTableParams.rows = [
    {
    sourceColumnOffset: 0,
    sortOrder: "ASCENDING",
      "showTotals": true,
       "valueBucket": {
                          "buckets": [
                            {
                              "stringValue": "Customer ID"
                            }
                          ]
                        }
    },
    {
    sourceColumnOffset: 2,
    sortOrder: "DESCENDING",
      "showTotals": true,
         "valueBucket": {
           "buckets": []
           }
    }

  ];

  // Defines how a value in a pivot table should be calculated.
  pivotTableParams.values = [
    {
    summarizeFunction: "SUM",
    sourceColumnOffset: 5
    },
    {
    summarizeFunction: "SUM",
    sourceColumnOffset: 6
    },
    {
    summarizeFunction: "SUM",
    sourceColumnOffset: 7
    },
  ];

  // Create a new sheet which will contain our Pivot Table
    var pivotsheet = ss.getSheetByName('Pivot Table - Campaigns');
    if (pivotsheet){
    ss.deleteSheet(pivotsheet);}
    var pivotTableSheet = ss.insertSheet('Pivot Table - Campaigns');
    var pivotTableSheetId = pivotTableSheet.getSheetId();

  // Add Pivot Table to new sheet
  // Meaning we send an 'updateCells' request to the Sheets API
  // Specifying via 'start' the sheet where we want to place our Pivot Table
  // And in 'rows' the parameters of our Pivot Table
  var request = {
    "updateCells": {
      "rows": {
        "values": [{
          "pivotTable": pivotTableParams
        }]
      },
      "start": {
        "sheetId": pivotTableSheetId
      },
      "fields": "pivotTable"
    }
  };

  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({'requests': [request]}, ss.getId());
return pivotTableSheetId
```

If I use this configuration, I can sort my pivot table by Grand total. By I can't sort by specific column in Grand Total.

For example, I have `sum of cost`, `sum of action`, `sum of clicks` in `Grand Total`. How can I make the pivot table to be sorted by one of those columns instead of random one?

Comment: Could you please provide a sample sheet so that there is more clarificatin in what you mean, specially with grand total?

Comment: For Grand total part, I have "sum of cost" in column I, and "sum of conversions" in column J, and "sum of cost" in column K. If I use the code I showed before, the pivot table will sort by column I by default. I want the pivot table sort by column K.

Comment: Hi ! A sample sheet could be very useful to test a possible solution, **please provide one if you can**. Also, I believe you would need specify your desired column for sorting in the ```criteria``` field of your pivot table when creating it. [Here you can find more information about this field](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/pivot-tables#pivottable) and [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/PivotFilterCriteria) more for the criteria itself. Let me know if that helped or if you can provide that sample sheet :D

Comment: Thanks Mateo. Considering the data is very sensitive, I can't provide you the sample data. But you can access the header of the sheet via https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1I9QgGJ3ahrjamZkzuw_wfU3i1-v9w_1IzJynMuvV1mk/edit?usp=sharing . I have stated my issue here is: when I creating the pivot table using the code I provided before, I can only sort the pivot on column I, but I want to sort the data on column K. That's my only requirement. And the filter criteria is not the right one. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: Hi! I have requested access to the resource you just share, could you please accept it? Also, could you try changing the ```sourceColumnOffset``` to 4 to check a thing just in case? Many thanks!

Comment: Thanks Mateo. I have granted your access. Besides, changing the sourceColumnOffset to 4 is not working

Comment: Hi! I could not manage to access the file as I am still denied the entry, could you please make your file public (removing all sensitive information or making a sample copy of it) or grant access to the request I just sent? Thank you very much in advance !

Comment: Hi! Could you please try the following and let me know if it worked? ```pivotTableParams.source = {
    sheetId: ss.getSheetByName(sheetName).getSheetId(),
    startRowIndex: 3
  };``` and ```pivotTableParams.rows = [{
    sourceColumnOffset: 8,
    sortOrder: "ASCENDING"
  }];``` to sort ```SUM OF CLICKS```. Let me know if that worked to formalise it into an answer with the rest of the piece of code. Also, you might find [this example](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/learn-by-example/google-sheets-api/pivot) really useful to fully understand pivot tables. Thanks!

Comment: Mateo, yes, I referred your example. My original code is sort by clicks by default. But I want to sort by SUM OF COST

Comment: I modify the question to put the full code for your reference. Thank you for your help.